# How to recreate PHAR files with identical sha1sums at different times?

Tags: php, phar

I'm working on a command-line PHP project and want to be able to recreate the PHAR file that is my deployment artifact. The challenge is that I can't create two PHAR's that have identical sha1sums and were created more than 1 second apart from each other. I would like to be able to exactly recreate my PHAR file if the input files are the same (i.e. came from the same git commit).

The following code snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$hashes = array();
$file_names = array('file1.phar','file2.phar');

foreach ($file_names as $name) {
  if (file_exists($name)) {
    unlink($name);
  }
  $phar = new Phar($name);
  $phar->addFromString('cli.php', "cli\n");
  $hashes[]=sha1_file($name);
  // remove the sleep and the PHAR's are identical.
  sleep(1);
}
if ($hashes[0]==$hashes[1]) {
  echo "match\n";
} else {
  echo "do not match\n";
}
```

As far as I can tell, the "modification time" field for each file in the PHAR manifest is always set to the current time, and there seems to be no way or overriding that. Even `touch("phar://file1.phar/cli.php", 1413387555)` gives the error:

```
touch(): Can not call touch() for a non-standard stream
```

I ran the above code in PHP 5.5.9 on ubuntu trusty and PHP 5.3 on RHEL5 and both versions behave the same way and fail to create identical PHAR files.

I'm trying to do this in order to follow the advice in the book *Continuous Deployment* by Jez Humble and David Farley

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change the system time.

Comment: It's very undesirable to change the time on production or even development servers. Even if you clobber the system time, then the PHAR files might still be different if the build process takes more or less time than the original run. Not to mention that some network operations, like those with kerberos, will fail if the system clock is vastly different from the rest of the world's time. Changing the 'system time' for a single command would be workable, but I'm aware of a way to do that, and it wo

Comment: Changing the 'system time' for a single command would be kludgey, but workable. I'm not aware of a way to change the system time for a single executable/command. As I understand, gettimeofday() is a kernel call that can't be intercepted by LD_PRELOAD. If I were to go to this level of effort, then changing the PHP source code or some type of post-processing seems more reasonable.

Comment: I stand corrected about changing the system time for a single program via LD_PRELOAD. It is possible to change the system time for a few processes using [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime). A large part of my hesitation to hacking the system time for a single process was the effort of writing my own library, but that's already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Phar class currently does not allow users to alter or even access the modifiction time. I thought of storing your string into a temporary file and using `touch` to alter the mtime, but that does not seem to have any effect. So you'll have to manually change the timestamps in the created files and then regenerate the archive signature. Here's how to do it with current PHP versions:

```php
<?php
    $filename = "file1.phar";

    $archive = file_get_contents($filename);

    # Search for the start of the archive header
    # See http://php.net/manual/de/phar.fileformat.phar.php
    # This isn't the only valid way to write a PHAR archive, but it is what the Phar class
    # currently does, so you should be fine (The docs say that the end-of-PHP-tag is optional)
    $magic = "__HALT_COMPILER(); ?" . ">";
    $end_of_code = strpos($archive, $magic) + strlen($magic);
    $data_pos = $end_of_code;

    # Skip that header
    $data = unpack("Vmanifest_length/Vnumber_of_files/vapi_version/Vglobal_flags/Valias_length", substr($archive, $end_of_code, 18));
    $data_pos += 18 + $data["alias_length"];
    $metadata = unpack("Vlength", substr($archive, $data_pos, 4));
    $data_pos += 4 + $metadata["length"];

    for($i=0; $i<$data["number_of_files"]; $i++) {
        # Now $data_pos points to the first file
        # Files are explained here: http://php.net/manual/de/phar.fileformat.manifestfile.php
        $filename_data = unpack("Vfilename_length", substr($archive, $data_pos, 4));
        $data_pos += 4 + $filename_data["filename_length"];
        $file_data = unpack("Vuncompressed_size/Vtimestamp/Vcompressed_size/VCRC32/Vflags/Vmetadata_length", substr($archive, $data_pos, 24));
        # Change the timestamp to zeros (You can also use some other time here using pack("V", time()) instead of the zeros)
        $archive = substr($archive, 0, $data_pos + 4) . "\0\0\0\0" . substr($archive, $data_pos + 8);
        # Skip to the next file (it's _all_ the headers first, then file data)
        $data_pos += 24 + $file_data["metadata_length"];
    }

    # Regenerate the file's signature
    $sig_data = unpack("Vsigflags/C4magic", substr($archive, strlen($archive) - 8));
    if($sig_data["magic1"] == ord("G") && $sig_data["magic2"] == ord("B") && $sig_data["magic3"] == ord("M") && $sig_data["magic4"] == ord("B")) {
        if($sig_data["sigflags"] == 1) {
            # MD5
            $sig_pos = strlen($archive) - 8 - 16;
            $archive = substr($archive, 0, $sig_pos) . pack("H32", md5(substr($archive, 0, $sig_pos))) . substr($archive, $sig_pos + 16);
        }
        else {
            # SHA1
            $sig_pos = strlen($archive) - 8 - 20;
            $archive = substr($archive, 0, $sig_pos) . pack("H40", sha1(substr($archive, 0, $sig_pos))) . substr($archive, $sig_pos + 20);
        }
        # Note: The manual talks about SHA256/SHA512 support, but the according flags aren't documented yet. Currently,
        # PHAR uses SHA1 by default, so there's nothing to worry about. You still might have to add those sometime.
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, $archive);
```

I've written this ad-hoc for my local PHP 5.5.9 version and your example above. The script will work for files created similar to your example code from above. The documentation hints to some valid deviations from this format. There are comments at the according lines in the code; you might have to add something there if you want to support general Phar files.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tested it and it works for my original code sample, but it fails if a stub is present. `createDefaultStub()` adds "\r\n" after the COMPILER_HALT. Using `$magic = "__HALT_COMPILER(); ?" . ">\r\n";` makes things work for the stub case.